# the induced verctor field of the compose map

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold, $\phi_t, \varphi_t: M\to M$, they induce two vector field, 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t=X_t\circ \phi, \frac{d}{dt}\varphi_t=X_t\circ \varphi,
$$
then what's the vector field induced by $\phi_t\circ\varphi_t$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $\phi_t$ and $\varphi_t$ supposed to be be flows on the manifold  M?

Comment: @THW Yes. They are flows.

Comment: First, I assume you meant for the second flow to have a vector field $Y$. Your notation is wrong: You should have $\dfrac d{dt}\phi_t = X\circ \phi_t$, not what you have. Why do you think there's a vector field associated to the composition? That will not, in general, be a $1$-parameter group of diffeomorphisms of $M$.